# Return value from HTTPResponse closure Grails HTTPBuilder to outer method

Tags: grails, closures, grails-controller, httpbuilder

I have some code like this

```
def lookupTickets() {
    User currentUser = webAuthService.currentUser()
    def http = new HTTPBuilder(zdURL)
    http.auth.basic("${zdUser}/token", zdApiKey)
    http.get(path: "/api/v2/users/search.json", 
             query: [query: currentUser.emailAddress], 
             requestContentType: ContentType.JSON, { resp, json ->
              println "Response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
                  def zenDeskUserId = json?.users[0]?.id
    })
    return MYRESULT
}
```

The line `def zenDeskUserId = json?.users[0]?.id` gives me the result I am looking to return to the browser.

How can I return this value in the outer method when it is only in scope from within the inner closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think this will not work?

```
def lookupTickets() {
    def zenDeskUserId

    User currentUser = webAuthService.currentUser()
    def http = new HTTPBuilder(zdURL)
    http.auth.basic("${zdUser}/token", zdApiKey)
    http.get(path: "/api/v2/users/search.json", 
             query: [query: currentUser.emailAddress], 
             requestContentType: ContentType.JSON, { resp, json ->

                 println "Response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
                 zenDeskUserId = json?.users[0]?.id
    })
    return zenDeskUserId
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the callback/closure would happen asynchronously.  This works.